# How make smaller eps files with gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I use

```
set terminal eps size 9cm,13cm enhanced
set output "Density5.0.eps"
...
plot 'density.dat' nonuniform matrix using 2:1:3 every 1:1 notitle with image
```

to make eps file from a big matrix. The file size is several mega bytes, too big for what I want to do with it.

One solution could be changing "every 1:1" with, say, "every 2:2", but this has negative impact on resolution.

I don't know much about the eps terminal or eps files. But it seems to me that if gnuplot can somehow save the image data as png or jpeg compressed images inside the eps files, the resulting files may be much smaller, particularly if jpeg compression is used.

The reason I don't use jpeg or pngcairo terminal instead is that I'd like to save vector graphics in the output file as well.

Comment: `set terminal eps level3` compresses the image data written by `plot ... with image`

Comment: @Christoph, It seem that in gnuplot 5.2 only the epslatex terminal has this level3 option. I'm using it now. It's helpful.

Comment: No, that option is also available for `eps`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `matrix with image`.

According to [this page](http://www.gnuplotting.org/tag/matrix/), an image should be smaller than actually plotting all the points.